# add graph lines behind d3 area chart

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to add graph lines (horizontal and vertical) to a area chart.

I would like my graph
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao3Rl.png)
to look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtDRG.png)

I have attempted to follow this example https://github.com/d3/d3-axis but it only adds the dotted lines too the left of the axis and I cannot understand why

I have created a stack blitz for anyone who cares to help:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dbhrnm?file=src%2Fapp%2FstackedArea-chart-visualization%2FstackedArea-chart-visualization.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2FstackedArea-chart-visualization%2FstackedArea-chart-visualization.component.html

Answer (score 0):

The best I found was to increase the ticksize to make them grids. So for example on your X Axis you can do something like this

```
.call(d3.axisBottom(x)
       .tickSize(-height)
```

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply.
thanks that's pretty helpful